# Delay program until download completes

Tags: python, time, urllib

I have some code to download content:

```
def downloadupdate():

    url = 'http://myurl.com/o/test/Super.zip'
    destination = xbmc.translatePath('somepath.zip')
    urllib.urlretrieve(url,destination)
    time.sleep(40)
```

Is there a way in Python to delay the script from running until the download has completed?  As you can see, I am currently using `time.sleep(x)` to accomplish this now, and in that I'm guessing at how long it will take. I'd rather have the script continue once the download is done, if this is possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can make it so that the urllib is synchronous, meaning it will block the rest of the program running until the download has finished.

```
import urllib
zip = urllib.urlopen('http://myurl.com/o/test/Super.zip')
with open(xbmc.translatePath('somepath.zip'), "wb") as zipFile:
    zipFile.write(zip.read())
# Download has Completed
print "Downloaded"
```

Comment: Note that [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/index.html) is a MUCH nicer module for doing stuff like this.  Also,  this method will load the entire file into memory (something to note if that zip file is very large).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, `urllib.urlretrieve()` isn't asynchronous in the first place, so you don't need to do any `time.sleep()` or similar to make the script block until retrieval is complete.